# I cannot open my files

Tags: 12.10, hard-drive

I had two partitions on my HD under windows. I decided to install Ubuntu, hoping it will install on partition where was Windows, so I transferred all my files to second partition, and now I cannot access them.

Comment: You can't see them? You can't open them? if yes,  any error message ?

Comment: Open `Disks` and check the partition structure. See if your data partition is still there.

Answer (score 1):

But is that partition still available? Did you install on the **whole** HD or you explicitly specified the partition to install onto?

I'm thinking of two things now:
1) You installed ubuntu on your harddrive, meaning, it combined those two partitions together as one, and installed on it. All your files are gone, thus :(
2) Your partition is still available, but you'll have to mount it. Try mounting it by clicking on its name in your Home Folder.

Thanks